# C++ static vs non static class members

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static, class-members

I have a class, let's call it `Foo`
`Foo` does not compile when I include the following line in the class in the header.

```
static std::vector<UnvalidatedSocket*> unvalidatedSockets;
```

and the following line in the cpp.

```
            Foo::unvalidatedSockets.push_back(new UnvalidatedSocket(ClientSocket));
```

when I take the `static`keyword away it compiles just fine.
I checked for circular includes but there are none.

The error is `LNK2001, unresolved external symbol`

Why does this happen?
Do static class members get included earlyer on?

Comment: static members need to be initialized not only declared. Add `std::vector<UnvalidatedSocket*> Foo::unvalidatedSocket;` to your cpp file.

Comment: Do not tell anybody what error you are getting, that would be much more interesting for people to guess...

Comment: Darnit.. I really don't like that you have to double declare stuff in c++. (Well, not really double declare.) Seems that there is still stuff a javadevelopper can learn

Comment: @blipman17 I really do not like when people do not ask questions properly, for example telling about errors and not showing them, calling linker errors "it does not compile" etc

Comment: dumb error from me, Added the error to the description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your static member somewhere in the CPP file before you try to push something onto it.  Add something like this:

```
std::vector<UnvalidatedSocket*> Foo::unvalidatedSockets;
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile this?

Comment: No need for `= std::vector()`, it will be default constructed automatically. Never mind the fact that it's incomplete.

Comment: @Slava Of course I have none of the OP's code, so there's nothing for me to compile... If the syntax is off, I'll be happy to correct it.

Comment: @Brick how do you expect this `std::vector();` to compile?

Comment: I'm trying to compile it right now.

Comment: It compiles, runs... perfect!

Comment: Dumb fact, I had this exact same problem earlyer but didn't recognise that that was actually thesame problem.